# Need help moving cursor to the beginning position in a UITextView Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have been trying to solve this issue for a few days. I will appreciate any help. If it makes a difference to you, my app is free and used by a lot of people who have lost the ability to speak on their own.

The app is text to speech. I am implementing a feature where if they type text and then hit the Return key, the following will occur:

- the text will automatically be spoken
- the text will be saved to a temp location in case they have to repeat what they said
- the screen will be cleared and an Undo button appears, so they can add the text back to the textView if needed (for repeating).

The problem I am having is when the Return key is pressed, the cursor moves down a line. I think it looks weird to have a clear textView with the cursor a line down (picture below). The rest works, even the Undo feature. I have tried many suggestions I have found here for moving the cursor programmatically and nothing seems to work.

Here is the code I use to do the previous steps. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [self speakText];
        self.clearedText = self.textView.text;
        self.undoReady = YES;
        [self.clearButton setTitle:@"Undo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.textView.text = @"";
        [WANT TO MOVE CURSOR TO BEGINNING POSITION];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @himanth for finding the possible duplicate. I did find my answer there.

Answer (score 4):

This is working fine for me.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
});
```

You can use this code whenever you want to set your textview position to start.

And change your range to `(1,0)` if you want your cursor to start after one letter.

Answer (score 0):

try with this-

```
textField.selectedTextRange = [textField
        textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
        toPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument];
```

Answer (score 0):

use the delegate method of textfield

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {}
```

The string gives you the key-character which you pressed.

Inside the method check for carriage return/ enter.

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"]) { }
```

then inside "If statement" after your code clear the textfield and move cursor to beginning through below  code.

```
//Your code
self.txtView.text = @"";
textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument];
```

Hope this will Help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) First Add UITextViewDelegate -

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>

2) To move the Cursor to the beginning position, use the Delegate method of TextView -

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol, which provides methods that let you control the selected range

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.selectedTextRange = [textField
        textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument
        toPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument];
}
```